# Search using Like Operator displaying the entered text in url using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i have implemented search functionality by following in youtube but the problem is whenever i enter the name and click on search button it is displaying that entered text in URL as mentioned below.

```
    <?php session_start();



if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch=$_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE 'first_name' LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search=filtertable($query);

}
else{
    $query="SELECT * FROM appointment";
    $search_result=filtertable($query);
}

    function filterTable($query)
    {
        include 'includes/db.php';
        $filter_Result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            return $filter_Result;      
    }

  ?>

<form>

          <input name="valueToSearch" type="text"  placeholder="Search  by Name"/>

          <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>

                <div class="body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Phonenumber</th>

                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <?php
                             while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>


                                    <tr>

                                        <td><?php echo $row['appoin_id'];?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?> </td>

                                        <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $row['department'];?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo $row['phone_no'];?></td>

                                    </tr>

                                <?php endwhile;?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

it is displaying in the url as like this

```
http://website.com/admin/search.php?valueToSearch=df&search=Search
```

And displaying the error in error log as  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: valueToSearch in admin/search.php on line 7.

Comment: You'll need to introduce that variable into your query, but to do that you'll need to use **a prepared statement with placeholder values**. For example: `WHERE first_name LIKE ?` and then bind `$_POST['search'] . '%'`.

Comment: @tadman not getting you can you explain little

Comment: If you've got no idea where to start that's fine, but it's a sign you could use some support. Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between. This is a solved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php session_start();



if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE first_name LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";        
    $search_result=filterTable($query);

}
else{
    $query="SELECT * FROM appointment";
    $search_result=filterTable($query);
    echo "No Records Found";
}

    function filterTable($query)
    {
        include 'includes/db.php';
        $filter_Result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            return $filter_Result;      
    }
```

?>